# Relatively prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of elements in the set $\{m:1\le m\le 1000,m$ and $1000$ are relatively prime$\}$.

My attempt: We are to find the number of elements which have only $1$ as the common factor with $1000$ i.e. the elements which are not the the multiples of $2$ and $5$. So, $1000-\{$(no. of multiples of $2$)$+$(no. of multiples of $5$)$-$(no.of multiples of $10$)$\}=1000-(500+200-100)=400$.

But the book solves it using a formula: $O(1000)=O(2^3)*O(5^3)=(2^3-2^2)(5^3-5^2)=4*100=400$. I don't understand what this formula is and how it is used. I wish somebody could explain. Thanks!

Comment: First: Your way is also correct. Then, the book uses a formula for the number - [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) - of coprime integers to $m$ not exceeding $m$ in terms of the prime factorisation of $m$. That is, iirc, explained well enough on the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the number of coprime elements of a given natural number is essential for all of modern algebra. The function that takes a given number $n$ to $\varphi (n)$ the number of coprime elements $\le n$ therefore has a special name "Euler totient function". The first thing to prove is that $\varphi$ is multiplicative, i.e. for coprime $m,n$ we  have $\varphi (mn)=\varphi (m)\varphi(n)$. An then you prove that for prime powers $p^n$ we have $\varphi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$ (simply by counting).